# In Android SDK version, 20 Why the development team removed "create project for existing source" in android Project creation window?

Tags: android

Recently i updated my android SDK from `Version 19` to `Version 20`. In the latest version has more features but i don't know how to import the existing android project in it. In `Version 19` when we click `File->New->Android Application Project`, a window having a field `"create project for existing source"`. But in `Version 20`, if i open the existing project means i'm using the following procedure, `File->Import->Android->Existing Android Code into WorkSpace`. Version 19 is more easier to create an application packages when compared to Version 20. Here i wish to know is there any other way to import an existing android project.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem: no, may i know,do you clear about my question?

Comment: Yes.." Here i wish to know is there any other way to import an existing android project."

Comment: I mentioned that line means, if i need any changes in android sdk settings. My theme is i need "create project for existing source" this option in project creation window, if i used your procedure means it takes more steps, but in previous one just enable the option.

Comment: you have edit your question 53min :) where you change the title..well dev of Android SDk will only able to give the answer of "Why"

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem: Well thanks for you response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
File > New > Other.. > Android > Android Project from Existing code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace
```

Try the one above.

Comment: @userlsAMoney:Thanks for your answer,but my question in Version 19 (and previous versions) having "create project for existing source" this field by default in android Project creation window. In version 20 Why the development team remove that?